# How to make a button conditional in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, conditional-statements, oracleforms

I am very new to oracle forms and I have to make a button conditional on my form.

The visibility of the button depends on user role.

The button should be visible only to a user whose role is 'admin'. If the role is 'super admin' the button should not be visible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `set_item_property` built-in and its `displayed` property.

You didn't explain how to know who is who, so I'll guess that it is contained in a global variable, so you'd then

```
if :global.user_role = 'super_admin' then
   set_item_property ('employees.btn_create_department', displayed, property_false);
elsif :global.user_role = 'admin' then
   set_item_property ('employees.btn_create_department', displayed, property_true);
end if;
```

For more info, open Forms Online Help system and read about that procedure.

Comment: And I have to write this code under trigger "when new form instance"?

Comment: Yes, or PRE-FORM, or any other suitable trigger.